# EasyAdmin 3.X - How to see related entities `toString` instead of the number of association in the list?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have an entity `Product` with a ManyToMany relation to an entity `Category`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Domain\Category", inversedBy="stalls")
 */
private $categories;

//...

/**
 * @return Collection|Category[]
 */
public function getCategories(): Collection
{
    return $this->categories;
}
```

In the `ProductCrudController` class I have the following `configureFields` method:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        Field::new('name'),
        Field::new('description'),
        AssociationField::new('categories'),
    ];
}
```

When creating/editing a `Product` everything works as expected in the relation, but in the list of products instead of showing the related categories I see the number of categories the product has. How can I change this behaviour?

In the following image the first product has 1 category and the second one in the list has 2 different categories. I would like the name of the categories to be shown here.

[image]

As a side note: `Category` class has a `__toString` method returning the name of the category.

EDIT:

The behaviour I am looking for is the same as the `Tags` column in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can format the value using the method `formatValue` like this :

```
->formatValue(function ($value, $entity) {
                $str = $entity->getCategories()[0];
                for ($i = 1; $i < $entity->getCategories()->count(); $i++) {
                    $str = $str . ", " . $entity->getCategories()[$i];
                }
                return $str;
              })
```

Comment: I will try this `formatValue` func, thanks. For the purpose of your solution maybe you can use `implode` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to return the same result?

Comment: Very good solution, but please not that this in its current form does not allow for code reuse if you need this for multiple entities.

Comment: Indeed, the implode variant is preferable, IMHO, as suggested by @hosseio, like:
``` php
AssociationField::new('categories')
                ->onlyOnDetail()
                ->formatValue(function ($value, $entity) {
                    return implode(', ', $entity->getCategories()->toArray());
                })
```

Answer (score 14):

You can make a template for that like so:

```
// somewhere here templates/admin/field/category.html.twig
{% for category in field.value %}
  {%- set url = ea_url()
    .setController('Path\\To\\Your\\CategoryCrudController')
    .setAction('detail')
    .setEntityId(category.id)
  -%}
  <a href="{{ url }}">
    {{ category.name }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
  </a>
{% else %}  
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">None</span>
{% endfor %}
```

And just add it to the field

```
// in ProductCrudController
AssociationField::new('categories')->setTemplatePath('admin/field/category.html.twig'),
```

Comment: This one should be the right answer, imo

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on my detail page. So instead of a template, I change the field type depending on the `pagename`

```
if (Crud::PAGE_DETAIL === $pageName) {
   $field = ArrayField::new('field')->setLabel('label');
} else {
   $field = AssociationField::new('field')->setLabel('label');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do that way :

```php
->formatValue(function ($value, $entity) {
    return implode(",",$entity->getCategories()->toArray());
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answers will have more long-term value if you include a brief explanation of why or how your code solves the asker’s question. Also, note that this question is over a year old and already has an accepted answer. That doesn’t mean you can’t still add an answer if you think your solution adds something the others don’t, but it would be more helpful to explain what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65082524/4381041), you could make the Twig snippet universal like this:

```
{% for member in field.value %}
    {%- if field.customOption('crudControllerFqcn') is not empty -%}
        {%- set url = ea_url()
            .setController(field.customOption('crudControllerFqcn'))
            .setAction('detail')
            .setEntityId(member.id)
        -%}
        <a href="{{ url }}">
            {{ member }}
        </a>
    {%- else -%}
        {{ member }}
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
{% else %}
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">None</span>
{% endfor %}
```

This way you could set the link destination in your CRUD controller and use the template everywhere. When no CRUD controller is not set, you will still have the individual items enumerated, but not as links.

In my TeamCrudController, I'm doing this:

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): \Generator
{
    yield TextField::new('name')
        ->setDisabled()
    ;

    $members = AssociationField::new('members')
        ->hideOnForm()

    ;

    if (Crud::PAGE_DETAIL === $pageName) { // I want to see the number on INDEX, but the list on DETAIL
        $members
            ->setCrudController(EmployeeCrudController::class)
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/expanded_association_field.html.twig')
        ;
    }

    yield $members;
}
```

Alternatively, **if you would like to become the default behaviour**, [override the EasyAdminBundle template](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/design.html#overriding-templates) by placing the following content in `templates/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/crud/field/association.html.twig`:

```
{# @var ea \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Context\AdminContext #}
{# @var field \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto #}
{# @var entity \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto #}
{% if 'toMany' == field.customOptions.get('associationType') %}
    {% if ea.crud.currentPage == 'detail' %}
        {% for member in field.value %}
            {%- if field.customOption('crudControllerFqcn') is not empty -%}
                {%- set url = ea_url()
                    .setController(field.customOption('crudControllerFqcn'))
                    .setAction('detail')
                    .setEntityId(member.id)
                -%}
                <a href="{{ url }}">
                    {{- member -}}
                </a>
            {%- else -%}
                {{ member }}
            {%- endif -%}

            {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
        {% else %}
            <span class="badge badge-secondary">None</span>
        {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
        <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ field.formattedValue }}</span>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% if field.customOptions.get('relatedUrl') is not null %}
        <a href="{{ field.customOptions.get('relatedUrl') }}">{{ field.formattedValue }}</a>
    {% else %}
        {{ field.formattedValue }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```