# How to display a column value in a badge in EasyAdmin 4?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I am making a CRUD in EasyAdmin 4. I have a table with a `status` column. I want to display it within a badge and change the badge color according its value. For example when the value is `in process` it must display with yellow color and when the value is `complete` it must be green.

Comment: Similar question that will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72351399/11350193